# How can I create Percona XtraDB cluster with Docker?

Tags: docker, percona, xtradb

- I need to create Percona XtraDB cluster with "star" topology: with one master node (where I insert data) and two slave nodes (changes in master must be applied to slaves)
- Also I need to use Docker for this.

#### What do I do:

- I use Docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/percona/percona-xtradb-cluster/:

  ```
  docker run --name xtradb -e CLUSTER_NAME=cluster -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 percona/percona-xtradb-cluster
  ```

I got output to my console:

```
Running --initialize-insecure on /var/lib/mysql/
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql 4.0K Dec  6 17:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root  root  4.0K Oct 29 00:12 ..
2016-12-06T17:49:10.703651Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-12-06T17:49:10.703793Z 0 [Warning] WSREP: Node is running in bootstrap/initialize mode. Disabling pxc_strict_mode checks
2016-12-06T17:49:11.082540Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2016-12-06T17:49:11.166052Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2016-12-06T17:49:11.219667Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 4b5149ee-bbdc-11e6-9aa1-0242ac110002.
2016-12-06T17:49:11.246135Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2016-12-06T17:49:11.489440Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2016-12-06T17:49:11.860045Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2016-12-06T17:49:12.488607Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:12.488721Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:12.488935Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:12.488977Z 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:12.489358Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
Finished --initialize-insecure
MySQL init process in progress...
2016-12-06T17:49:15.343012Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-12-06T17:49:15.344705Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.14-8-57) starting as process 41 ...
2016-12-06T17:49:15.347186Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
2016-12-06T17:49:15.347427Z 0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib/galera3/libgalera_smm.so'
2016-12-06T17:49:15.351457Z 0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 3.17(r447d194) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.351682Z 0 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using hardware acceleration.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.352398Z 0 [Warning] WSREP: Could not open state file for reading: '/var/lib/mysql//grastate.dat'
2016-12-06T17:49:15.352545Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
2016-12-06T17:49:15.356038Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_dir = /var/lib/mysql/; base_host = 172.17.0.2; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; debug = no; evs.auto_evict = 0; evs.delay_margin = PT1S; evs.delayed_keep_period = PT30S; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 3; evs.send_window = 4; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 2; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_count = 0; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /var/lib/mysql//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.size = 128M; gcomm.thread_prio = ; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.segment = 0; gmcast.version = 0; pc.announce_timeout = PT3S; pc.checksum = false
2016-12-06T17:49:15.399119Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.399261Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: -1, protocol version: -1
2016-12-06T17:49:15.399486Z 0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_sst_grab()
2016-12-06T17:49:15.399647Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
2016-12-06T17:49:15.399804Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
2016-12-06T17:49:15.399924Z 0 [Note] WSREP: protonet asio version 0
2016-12-06T17:49:15.400319Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Using CRC-32C for message checksums.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.400411Z 0 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
2016-12-06T17:49:15.400657Z 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm thread scheduling priority set to other:0
2016-12-06T17:49:15.400797Z 0 [Warning] WSREP: access file(/var/lib/mysql//gvwstate.dat) failed(No such file or directory)
2016-12-06T17:49:15.401003Z 0 [Note] WSREP: restore pc from disk failed
2016-12-06T17:49:15.403105Z 0 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
2016-12-06T17:49:15.405058Z 0 [Note] WSREP: (4dcf57f4, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
2016-12-06T17:49:15.405301Z 0 [Note] WSREP: (4dcf57f4, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
2016-12-06T17:49:15.409642Z 0 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 0
2016-12-06T17:49:15.410146Z 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'Theistareykjarbunga', peer ''
2016-12-06T17:49:15.411849Z 0 [Note] WSREP: start_prim is enabled, turn off pc_recovery
2016-12-06T17:49:15.412522Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Node 4dcf57f4 state prim
2016-12-06T17:49:15.412731Z 0 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,4dcf57f4,1) memb {
        4dcf57f4,0
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
})
2016-12-06T17:49:15.413170Z 0 [Note] WSREP: save pc into disk
2016-12-06T17:49:15.413448Z 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
2016-12-06T17:49:15.413841Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
2016-12-06T17:49:15.413924Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
2016-12-06T17:49:15.414182Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'Theistareykjarbunga'
2016-12-06T17:49:15.417075Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.421054Z 0 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 1
2016-12-06T17:49:15.429569Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Starting new group from scratch: 4dd38c07-bbdc-11e6-9e05-ff24cdfdc605
2016-12-06T17:49:15.432205Z 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE_EXCHANGE: sent state UUID: 4dd3f402-bbdc-11e6-badb-ca345528032f
2016-12-06T17:49:15.432821Z 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 4dd3f402-bbdc-11e6-badb-ca345528032f
2016-12-06T17:49:15.433725Z 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 4dd3f402-bbdc-11e6-badb-ca345528032f from 0 (6814cd5862dd)
2016-12-06T17:49:15.434021Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
        version    = 4,
        component  = PRIMARY,
        conf_id    = 0,
        members    = 1/1 (joined/total),
        act_id     = 0,
        last_appl. = -1,
        protocols  = 0/7/3 (gcs/repl/appl),
        group UUID = 4dd38c07-bbdc-11e6-9e05-ff24cdfdc605
2016-12-06T17:49:15.434743Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [16, 16]
2016-12-06T17:49:15.434898Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Restored state OPEN -> JOINED (0)
2016-12-06T17:49:15.435307Z 1 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 4dd38c07-bbdc-11e6-9e05-ff24cdfdc605:0, view# 1: Primary, number of nodes: 1, my index: 0, protocol version 3
2016-12-06T17:49:15.435407Z 0 [Note] WSREP: SST complete, seqno: 0
2016-12-06T17:49:15.437118Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2016-12-06T17:49:15.437801Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-12-06T17:49:15.438830Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2016-12-06T17:49:15.439745Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2016-12-06T17:49:15.442794Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-12-06T17:49:15.443451Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-12-06T17:49:15.443796Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2016-12-06T17:49:15.444197Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-12-06T17:49:15.445949Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Member 0.0 (6814cd5862dd) synced with group.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.448773Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting JOINED -> SYNCED (TO: 0)
2016-12-06T17:49:15.453625Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2016-12-06T17:49:15.466242Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-12-06T17:49:15.468558Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2016-12-06T17:49:15.481743Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Crash recovery did not find the parallel doublewrite buffer at /var/lib/mysql/xb_doublewrite
2016-12-06T17:49:15.486318Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.522431Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Created parallel doublewrite buffer at /var/lib/mysql/xb_doublewrite, size 3932160 bytes
2016-12-06T17:49:15.548331Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2016-12-06T17:49:15.548465Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2016-12-06T17:49:15.559240Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.562965Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.563078Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.564561Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-12-06T17:49:15.615700Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.7.14-8 started; log sequence number 2491156
2016-12-06T17:49:15.619333Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.629815Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2016-12-06T17:49:15.635698Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.636018Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.642714Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.643054Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.653055Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.653222Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.653494Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 161206 17:49:15
2016-12-06T17:49:15.653568Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.653838Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.666732Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.673941Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2016-12-06T17:49:15.678543Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.14-8-57'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel8, Revision a3f9d06, WSREP version 26.17, wsrep_26.17
2016-12-06T17:49:15.681560Z 1 [Note] WSREP: Initialized wsrep sidno 2
2016-12-06T17:49:15.681661Z 1 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.681852Z 1 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 7 (3, 2)
2016-12-06T17:49:15.681899Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.682066Z 1 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 0, protocol version: 3
2016-12-06T17:49:15.682224Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2016-12-06T17:49:15.682439Z 1 [Note] WSREP: Synchronized with group, ready for connections
2016-12-06T17:49:15.682481Z 1 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Factory' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Factory' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Factory' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.650211Z 7 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.650386Z 7 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.650614Z 7 [Warning] 'user' entry 'xtrabackup@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.650655Z 7 [Warning] 'user' entry 'monitor@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.650856Z 7 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.650899Z 7 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.651181Z 7 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.653727Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Stop replication
2016-12-06T17:49:18.654028Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Closing send monitor...
2016-12-06T17:49:18.654495Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Closed send monitor.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.654616Z 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: terminating thread
2016-12-06T17:49:18.655589Z 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: joining thread
2016-12-06T17:49:18.656926Z 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closing backend
2016-12-06T17:49:18.658959Z 0 [Note] WSREP: view((empty))
2016-12-06T17:49:18.660103Z 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closed
2016-12-06T17:49:18.661882Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Received self-leave message.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.662356Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [0, 0]
2016-12-06T17:49:18.662411Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Received SELF-LEAVE. Closing connection.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.662868Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting SYNCED -> CLOSED (TO: 13)
2016-12-06T17:49:18.662966Z 0 [Note] WSREP: RECV thread exiting 0: Success
2016-12-06T17:49:18.663075Z 4 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 4dd38c07-bbdc-11e6-9e05-ff24cdfdc605:13, view# -1: non-Primary, number of nodes: 0, my index: -1, protocol version 3
2016-12-06T17:49:18.663752Z 4 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.663852Z 4 [Note] WSREP: applier thread exiting (code:0)
2016-12-06T17:49:18.665487Z 0 [Note] WSREP: recv_thread() joined.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.666011Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Closing replication queue.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.666660Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Closing slave action queue.
2016-12-06T17:49:18.673299Z 1 [Note] WSREP: applier thread exiting (code:6)
2016-12-06T17:49:20.667240Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 1 remaining clients
2016-12-06T17:49:20.667378Z 2 [Note] WSREP: rollbacker thread exiting
2016-12-06T17:49:20.667851Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2016-12-06T17:49:20.667902Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2016-12-06T17:49:20.668072Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2016-12-06T17:49:20.668208Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2016-12-06T17:49:20.668383Z 0 [Note] WSREP: dtor state: CLOSED
2016-12-06T17:49:20.674153Z 0 [Note] WSREP: mon: entered 13 oooe fraction 0 oool fraction 0
2016-12-06T17:49:20.688689Z 0 [Note] WSREP: mon: entered 13 oooe fraction 0 oool fraction 0
2016-12-06T17:49:20.705880Z 0 [Note] WSREP: mon: entered 17 oooe fraction 0 oool fraction 0
2016-12-06T17:49:20.706271Z 0 [Note] WSREP: cert index usage at exit 0
2016-12-06T17:49:20.707073Z 0 [Note] WSREP: cert trx map usage at exit 9
2016-12-06T17:49:20.707367Z 0 [Note] WSREP: deps set usage at exit 0
2016-12-06T17:49:20.708561Z 0 [Note] WSREP: avg deps dist 1
2016-12-06T17:49:20.708778Z 0 [Note] WSREP: avg cert interval 0
2016-12-06T17:49:20.709342Z 0 [Note] WSREP: cert index size 134659
2016-12-06T17:49:20.775344Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2016-12-06T17:49:20.779232Z 0 [Note] WSREP: wsdb trx map usage 0 conn query map usage 0
2016-12-06T17:49:20.779340Z 0 [Note] WSREP: MemPool(LocalTrxHandle): hit ratio: 0.307692, misses: 9, in use: 0, in pool: 9
2016-12-06T17:49:20.779687Z 0 [Note] WSREP: MemPool(SlaveTrxHandle): hit ratio: 0, misses: 0, in use: 0, in pool: 0
2016-12-06T17:49:20.779956Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> DESTROYED (TO: 13)
2016-12-06T17:49:20.780299Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Flushing memory map to disk...
2016-12-06T17:49:20.793824Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2016-12-06T17:49:20.794999Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.795209Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.795243Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.795535Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.795591Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.795742Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.795797Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.795981Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.796033Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.796208Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.796242Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CHANGED_PAGES'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.796538Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.796608Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.796731Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.796761Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.796884Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.796911Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.797046Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.797074Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.797192Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.797226Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.797419Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.797463Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.797576Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.797617Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.797798Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.797839Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.798021Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.798167Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.798457Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.798507Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.798706Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.798741Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.799066Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.799159Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.799598Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.799646Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.799775Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.799807Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.800011Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.800194Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'XTRADB_RSEG'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.800339Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'XTRADB_INTERNAL_HASH_TABLES'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.800380Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'XTRADB_READ_VIEW'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.800553Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2016-12-06T17:49:20.800932Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2016-12-06T17:49:20.801288Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2016-12-06T17:49:20.902647Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2016-12-06T17:49:20.902941Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 161206 17:49:20
2016-12-06T17:49:22.634067Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 12099523
2016-12-06T17:49:22.634992Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2016-12-06T17:49:22.636093Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2016-12-06T17:49:22.636314Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2016-12-06T17:49:22.637397Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'wsrep'
2016-12-06T17:49:22.638613Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2016-12-06T17:49:22.646108Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete


MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

2016-12-06T17:49:22.908420Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-12-06T17:49:22.909260Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.14-8-57) starting as process 1 ...
2016-12-06T17:49:22.911520Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
2016-12-06T17:49:22.911724Z 0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib/galera3/libgalera_smm.so'
2016-12-06T17:49:22.915717Z 0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 3.17(r447d194) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
2016-12-06T17:49:22.916056Z 0 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using hardware acceleration.
2016-12-06T17:49:22.916756Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 4dd38c07-bbdc-11e6-9e05-ff24cdfdc605:13
2016-12-06T17:49:22.917543Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_dir = /var/lib/mysql/; base_host = 172.17.0.2; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; debug = no; evs.auto_evict = 0; evs.delay_margin = PT1S; evs.delayed_keep_period = PT30S; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 3; evs.send_window = 4; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 2; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_count = 0; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /var/lib/mysql//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.size = 128M; gcomm.thread_prio = ; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.segment = 0; gmcast.version = 0; pc.announce_timeout = PT3S; pc.checksum = false
2016-12-06T17:49:22.937056Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2016-12-06T17:49:22.937196Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 13, protocol version: -1
2016-12-06T17:49:22.937480Z 0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_sst_grab()
2016-12-06T17:49:22.937525Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
2016-12-06T17:49:22.937745Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 4dd38c07-bbdc-11e6-9e05-ff24cdfdc605:13
2016-12-06T17:49:22.937863Z 0 [Note] WSREP: protonet asio version 0
2016-12-06T17:49:22.938502Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Using CRC-32C for message checksums.
2016-12-06T17:49:22.938655Z 0 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
2016-12-06T17:49:22.939359Z 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm thread scheduling priority set to other:0
2016-12-06T17:49:22.941844Z 0 [Warning] WSREP: access file(/var/lib/mysql//gvwstate.dat) failed(No such file or directory)
2016-12-06T17:49:22.942719Z 0 [Note] WSREP: restore pc from disk failed
2016-12-06T17:49:22.946124Z 0 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
2016-12-06T17:49:22.946553Z 0 [Note] WSREP: (524e2801, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
2016-12-06T17:49:22.946787Z 0 [Note] WSREP: (524e2801, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
2016-12-06T17:49:22.948351Z 0 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 0
2016-12-06T17:49:22.948530Z 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'cluster', peer ''
2016-12-06T17:49:22.948926Z 0 [Note] WSREP: start_prim is enabled, turn off pc_recovery
2016-12-06T17:49:22.949137Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Node 524e2801 state prim
2016-12-06T17:49:22.949772Z 0 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,524e2801,1) memb {
        524e2801,0
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
})
2016-12-06T17:49:22.949844Z 0 [Note] WSREP: save pc into disk
2016-12-06T17:49:22.950334Z 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
2016-12-06T17:49:22.950414Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
2016-12-06T17:49:22.951083Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
2016-12-06T17:49:22.951181Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'cluster'
2016-12-06T17:49:22.951614Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete.
2016-12-06T17:49:22.951824Z 0 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 1
2016-12-06T17:49:22.953494Z 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE_EXCHANGE: sent state UUID: 524f9e4e-bbdc-11e6-9190-b66393d75772
2016-12-06T17:49:22.953585Z 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 524f9e4e-bbdc-11e6-9190-b66393d75772
2016-12-06T17:49:22.953825Z 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 524f9e4e-bbdc-11e6-9190-b66393d75772 from 0 (6814cd5862dd)
2016-12-06T17:49:22.953904Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
        version    = 4,
        component  = PRIMARY,
        conf_id    = 0,
        members    = 1/1 (joined/total),
        act_id     = 13,
        last_appl. = -1,
        protocols  = 0/7/3 (gcs/repl/appl),
        group UUID = 4dd38c07-bbdc-11e6-9e05-ff24cdfdc605
2016-12-06T17:49:22.954201Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [16, 16]
2016-12-06T17:49:22.954388Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Restored state OPEN -> JOINED (13)
2016-12-06T17:49:22.954772Z 1 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 4dd38c07-bbdc-11e6-9e05-ff24cdfdc605:13, view# 1: Primary, number of nodes: 1, my index: 0, protocol version 3
2016-12-06T17:49:22.954848Z 0 [Note] WSREP: SST complete, seqno: 13
2016-12-06T17:49:22.959718Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2016-12-06T17:49:22.959984Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-12-06T17:49:22.960376Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2016-12-06T17:49:22.960571Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2016-12-06T17:49:22.959959Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Member 0.0 (6814cd5862dd) synced with group.
2016-12-06T17:49:22.961183Z 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting JOINED -> SYNCED (TO: 13)
2016-12-06T17:49:22.961467Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-12-06T17:49:22.961518Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-12-06T17:49:22.962451Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2016-12-06T17:49:22.963873Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-12-06T17:49:22.970069Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2016-12-06T17:49:22.980110Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-12-06T17:49:22.985756Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().

<part of output is truncated>
```

- docker ps -a

  ```
  CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                     NAMES
  6814cd5862dd        percona/percona-xtradb-cluster   "/entrypoint.sh "        10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes                  3306/tcp, 4567-4568/tcp   xtradb
  ```

#### The quastions are:

- how can I access to database in cluster?
- how can I add slave nodes to cluster?
- how can I get cluster node list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a multi-host environment, you can check https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/06/10/percona-xtradb-cluster-in-a-multi-host-docker-network/

If not, I've been working on some projects on this, feel free to check https://github.com/guriandoro/docker/tree/master/pxc, and in particular https://github.com/guriandoro/docker/tree/master/pxc/N-node-pxc.

In the readme, you can find how to connect to them, and how to get the list of running nodes. What do you mean by slave nodes, though? Regular async replication? Or to add more nodes to the cluster?

Let me know if it helps, or if you have any feedback on it. It's a work in progress, but you should be able to quickly have some nodes running in one host with minimal tweaking.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have additional questions. 1) I have started 2 nodes and proxysql (with `docker-compose up proxysql` command) and have 4 containers running (`docker-compose ps`): `node1`, `node2`, `etcd`, `proxysql`. How can I access database not attaching to container (only using `mysql` command). 2) how can I use custom `my.cnf` with containers. 3) I want to build "start" topology (with one "master" node - all INSERT queries will be forwarded to it, other nodes are "slave" - all SELECT queries are forwarded to them). I will be very grateful for your help!

Comment: 1) you can use `docker inspect <container-name> | grep IPv4Address` to check the IP address for the container, and then use the mysql client to connect to it, like `mysql -h<container-IP-address> -uroot -proot`.

Comment: 2) this is still a work in progress, but you can build your own containers and add your custom my.cnf files. Then, just edit the docker-compose.yml files to use your custom container images. I will add the ability to use custom container images soon (by editing the .env file), it's easy enough, but I've been working on other tasks.

Comment: 3) for this, you will need to configure proxysql to do the split for you. You can find more information about this in blogs (like [https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/09/15/proxysql-percona-cluster-galera-integration/]). Also, note that the proxysql project is still a work in progress, and needs more work in the etcd and proxysql containers. Any feedback you have on it (feel free to use github directly) is most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Depend on other [snippets](https://itc-life.ru/percona-xtradb-cluster-5-7-with-consul-in-docker-swarm-cluster/),let's create percona xtradb cluster 8.0 with consul in docker swarm cluster

Create percona xtradb cluster in docker swarm cluster.

### REQUIREMENTS

- 3 nodes swarm workers(node1,node2,node3)
- 1 node swarm manager(node4)

Ip's v4 nodes

```sh
node1 - swarm worker - 192.168.1.108
node2 - swarm worker - 192.168.1.109
node3 - swarm worker - 192.168.1.110
node4 - swarm manager - 192.168.1.111
```

### PREPARE

Add label to swarm nodes

```sh
docker node update --label-add pxc=true node1
docker node update --label-add pxc=true node2
docker node update --label-add pxc=true node3
docker node update --label-add consul=true node4
```

Set heartbeat period

```sh
docker swarm update --dispatcher-heartbeat 20s
```

Make directories

```sh
mkdir -p /docker-compose/SWARM/pxc8/configs/consul
```

Create config file consul server

```sh
vim /docker-compose/SWARM/pxc8/configs/consul/config.json
```

```json
{ 
  "advertise_addr" : "{{ GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\" }}",
  "bind_addr": "{{ GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\" }}",
  "addresses" : {
    "http" : "0.0.0.0"
  },
  "ports" : {
    "server": 8300,
    "http": 8500,
    "dns": 8600
  },
  "skip_leave_on_interrupt": true,
  "server_name" : "pxc.service.consul",
  "primary_datacenter":"dc1",
  "acl_default_policy":"allow",
  "acl_down_policy":"extend-cache",
  "datacenter":"dc1",
  "data_dir":"/consul/data",
  "bootstrap": true,
  "server":true,
  "ui" : true

}
```

Create docker compose file

```sh
vim /docker-compose/SWARM/pxc8/docker-compose.yml
```

```sh
version: '3.6'

services:
  
  consul:
    image: "devsadds/consul:1.8.3"
    hostname: consul
    volumes:
      - "/docker-compose/SWARM/pxc8/configs/consul:/consul/config"
    ports:
      - target: 8500
        published: 8500
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      pxc8-net:
        aliases:
          - pxc.service.consul
    command: "consul agent -config-file /consul/config/config.json"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 15s
        max_attempts: 13
        window: 18s
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 20s
        failure_action: continue
        monitor: 60s
        max_failure_ratio: 0.3
      placement:
        constraints: [ node.labels.consul  == true ]

  pxc:
    image: "devsadds/pxc:8.0.19-10.1-consul-1.8.3-focal-v1.1.0"
    environment:
      CLUSTER_NAME: "percona"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root32456"
      MYSQL_PROXY_USER: "mysqlproxyuser"
      MYSQL_PROXY_PASSWORD: "mysqlproxy32456"
      PXC_SERVICE: "pxc.service.consul"
      DISCOVERY_SERVICE: "consul"
      DATADIR: "/var/lib/mysql"
      MONITOR_PASSWORD: "mys3232323323"
      XTRABACKUP_PASSWORD: "mys3232323323"
    volumes:
      - "pxc_8_0:/var/lib/mysql"
    networks:
      pxc8-net:
        aliases:
          - mysql
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 15s
        max_attempts: 23
        window: 180s
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 20s
        failure_action: continue
        monitor: 60s
        max_failure_ratio: 0.3
      placement:
        constraints: [ node.labels.pxc  == true ]


volumes:
  pxc_8_0:

networks:
  pxc8-net:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.23.0.0/24
```

Deploy stack

```sh
cd /docker-compose/SWARM/pxc8
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml pxc8 --resolve-image always --prune --with-registry-auth
```

Go to web ui(unsecured)

http://192.168.1.111:8500/ui/dc1/services/pxc8/instances

Wait until first node in cluster ok.

Then scale to 3 nodes

```sh
docker service scale pxc8_pxc=3 -d
```

Wait until cluster scale.

### Scale cluster to one node

```sh
docker service scale pxc8_pxc=1 -d
```

Cluster with one node become   non-Primary  and not ready for operations

```sql
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_status';

+----------------------+---------+
| Variable_name        | Value   |
+----------------------+---------+
| wsrep_cluster_status | non-Primary |
+----------------------+---------+
```

After scale to one node, exec command on the last node with pxc(Most Advanced Node) make cluster Primary from non-Primary state

```sql
SET GLOBAL wsrep_provider_options='pc.bootstrap=YES';
```

The node now operates as the starting node in a new Primary Component.

```sql
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_status';

+----------------------+---------+
| Variable_name        | Value   |
+----------------------+---------+
| wsrep_cluster_status | Primary |
+----------------------+---------+
```

Now we can scale our cluster to 3 or more nodes

```sh
docker service scale pxc8_pxc=3 -d
```

### Fix cluster after crash all nodes

Edit file and set  safe_to_bootstrap to 1 on node with latest data.

```sh
cd /docker-compose/SWARM/pxc8
docker stack rm pxc8
```

Edit file  /var/lib/docker/volumes/pxc8_pxc_8_0/_data/gvwstate.dat

```sh
nano /var/lib/docker/volumes/pxc8_pxc_8_0/_data/gvwstate.dat
```

```sh
my_uuid: 505b00f5-f33a-11ea-9ee4-abd76ca92272
#vwbeg
view_id: 3 505b00f5-f33a-11ea-9ee4-abd76ca92272 52
bootstrap: 0
member: 505b00f5-f33a-11ea-9ee4-abd76ca92272 0
member: 88f6da78-f1fc-11ea-81cc-e386dd9bf4d3 0
member: 91aaf3ec-f33a-11ea-88f8-93c04e238f30 0
#vwend
```

And make changes

```sh
my_uuid: 505b00f5-f33a-11ea-9ee4-abd76ca92272
#vwbeg
view_id: 3 505b00f5-f33a-11ea-9ee4-abd76ca92272 52
bootstrap: 0
member: 505b00f5-f33a-11ea-9ee4-abd76ca92272 0
#vwend
```

Edit file /var/lib/docker/volumes/pxc8_pxc_8_0/_data/grastate.dat

```sh
nano /var/lib/docker/volumes/pxc8_pxc_8_0/_data/grastate.dat
```

```sh
safe_to_bootstrap 1
```

and stark cluster with one node again

```sh
cd /docker-compose/SWARM/pxc8
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml pxc8 --resolve-image always --prune --with-registry-auth
```

### Reconnect pxc nodes to consul docker, if consul docker restarted

Go into container with pxc

```
ps aux | grep consul
```

kill consul agent

```
kill -9 13
```

and run process again in foregroud, with last command, added at the end of line

```sh
 /bin/consul agent -retry-join consul -client 0.0.0.0 -bind 10.22.0.17 -node -99f341353c95 -data-dir /tmp -config-file /tmp/pxc.json &amp;
```